# Django-Python list saved in DB how to access in template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am getting data from an API and saved in `models.py` as part of learning Django.
I got data and it is saved in db as it is.

```
[u'RASH ERYTHEMATOUS', u'PAIN', u'FEELING HOT', u'PRURITUS', u'PAIN OF SKIN', u'SKIN IRRITATION', u'PARAESTHESIA', u'DERMATITIS CONTACT']
```

Now when I try to access this data in template I getting this list only and not able to show it in a user friendly manner.
I have tried:

```
{% for data in datalist.items %}
{{data}}
{% endfor %}
```

But result output in template html will be

```
[u'RASH ERYTHEMATOUS', u'PAIN', u'FEELING HOT', u'PRURITUS', u'PAIN OF SKIN', u'SKIN IRRITATION', u'PARAESTHESIA', u'DERMATITIS CONTACT']
```

I need something like RASH ERYTHEMATOUS, PAIN ,FEELING HOT .....

Edited: Further details

I get some data from API.
I convert API json to json.loads(data) and save it in `models.py`
Now in API a particular sub set is saved in models.py as `[u'RASH ERYTHEMATOUS', u'PAIN', u'FEELING HOT', u'PRURITUS', u'PAIN OF SKIN', u'SKIN IRRITATION', u'PARAESTHESIA', u'DERMATITIS CONTACT']` because json.loads() converts json data to python readable format.

I have saved it in `models.py`
I can retrieve this data in template but its coming as `[u'RASH ERYTHEMATOUS', u'PAIN', u'FEELING HOT', u'PRURITUS', u'PAIN OF SKIN', u'SKIN IRRITATION', u'PARAESTHESIA', u'DERMATITIS CONTACT']`
Now I cannot display it by removing `[u'`

Update:
Nothing worked. Tried following code and it did the magic.

```
def reactiondata(self):
        return self.reactions.replace("[",'').replace("u",'').replace("'",'').replace(']','').split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that you don't explain how the data is stored nor show your models:

If the `data` variable is still printing as a list instead of single objects, you could try to iterate over that variable again like this:

```
{% for data in datalist.items %}
    {% for elem in data %}
        {{ elem }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or you could use the [`join` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#join)

```
{% for data in datalist.items %}
    {{ data|join:', ' }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont have json list. Its Django converted list that is stored in DB.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. My answer is not specific for json lists, but should work for them too. Please explain why exactly this is not working for you? Or maybe edit your question to show how the list is stored in the DB (show your models) and how it is retrieved from the DB and passed to your template.

Comment: updated question with exact what I am looking for. I need to remove `[u'`

Comment: `[u'` indicates that it is a unicode string (you probably are using Python 2.x). Have you tried any of my two suggestions in my answer? Both of them should remove the `u` prefix when rendering the individual elements of the list.

Comment: the db is likely storing the data as a string representation of a JSON object, it is NOT a list, but a string representing that list.  And this computer-intentded string representation is what you are printing in the template.  You need to `json.loads(data.mylist)` (remember to `import json`).  This casts it to a proper Python list which won't have `u'` stuff when you template that Python list.

Comment: Nothing worked, had to go with replace method. Updated question.